# nginx config to serve as external secure proxy

Tags: nginx

I'm setting up an external nginx server to proxy all outgoing traffic in order to simplify outbound firewall rules.

What I'd like is:

- https://service1.com.example.com --> https://service1.com:443
- https://www.service2.com.example.com --> https://www.service2.com:443
- https://service3.com.example.com --> http://service3.com:8080
- (everything else denied)

(There will be 30-40 different hosts here, so I'm looking for something relatively easy to maintain.)

**Is this possible with Nginx?** Or is there some other proxy software that is better suited for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

nginx makes a great reverse proxy, but is less than ideal as a forward proxy. [It can be done](http://ef.gy/xhtml/using-nginx-as-a-proxy-server), but since writing the rules you want will be rather hairy, you're almost certainly better off to use a purpose-built forward proxy, such as squid. Doing so also means your future self will have a much better chance of understanding what's going on when trying to maintain or debug the proxy.